# Family tree doesn't stretch

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a large family tree but i run into this problem. When i was making it i ran this problem. The problem is that the names come on top of each other if the names of the 2 sides of the family is large it comes under all the 1st side of the family. I want to stretch it to make it scroll left and right for all of the family tree to appear.

(these are just example names)

I found this family tree online Here is original family tree i found online: https://codepen.io/Pestov/pen/AvQmxv

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}


/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}


/*Remove space from the top of single children*/

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}


/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}


/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}


/*add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*hover effects*/


/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/

.tree li a:hover,
.tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}


/*Connector styles on hover*/

.tree li a:hover+ul li::after,
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">simon</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">jake</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">olivia</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Lucas</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">james</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">benjamin</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">liam</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Emily</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">noah</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">oliver</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">mona</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">layla</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">simon</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">mona</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">adam</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">william</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">karla</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">jacob</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">jhon</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">jack</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">elijah</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">james</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">benjamin</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">liam</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">jack</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">sam</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">mona</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">karla</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">jacob</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">tim</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">joseph</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">jake</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">david</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">mona</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">layla</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">vennesa</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use max-content value on width property for your li tag

```
width: max-content;
```

> The max-content sizing keyword represents the intrinsic maximum width
> or height of the content. For text content this means that the content
> will not wrap at all even if it causes overflows.

```
.tree li {
    width: max-content; // add this line to your css
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

below is a working snippet

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  width: max-content;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}


/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}


/*Remove space from the top of single children*/

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}


/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}


/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}


/*add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*hover effects*/


/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/

.tree li a:hover,
.tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}


/*Connector styles on hover*/

.tree li a:hover+ul li::after,
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">simon</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">jake</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">olivia</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Lucas</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">james</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">benjamin</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">liam</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Emily</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">noah</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">oliver</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">mona</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">layla</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">simon</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">mona</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">adam</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">william</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">karla</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">jacob</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">jhon</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">jack</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">elijah</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">james</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">benjamin</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">liam</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">jack</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">sam</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">mona</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">karla</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">jacob</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">tim</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">joseph</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">jake</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">david</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">mona</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">layla</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">vennesa</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```